# Implementing Array#uniq in Ruby

Tags: ruby, array

I've implemented a working version of Array#uniq in Ruby to answer the question here: http://www.rubeque.com/problems/like-a-snowflake, but I'd like to see if there's ways to clean up my code or some better practices I should follow?  This is my version:

```
class Array
  def uniq(&block)
    objs = []
    yield_vals = []
    self.each do |obj|
      yield_val = yield obj
      unless yield_vals.include?(yield_val)
        yield_vals.push(yield_val)
        objs.push(obj)
      end
    end
    objs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For one, I'd use the `<<` operator rather than `push` just out of convention.

Second, you still have other Array/Enumerable methods at your disposal. So there's no need to create a new array and add unique items to it. Try filtering the array instead.

Update: Whoo boy, I was still asleep when I wrote that first answer. In my defense it *was* early

You can actually just do

```
def uniq(&block)
  group_by(&block).values.map(&:first)
end
```

As for my previous answer... well, I did say it could be done better. Just pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot, both of your solutions really helped me.

Comment: Nice simple solution. Only that you pay a bit of storage penalty.

Comment: @tokland thanks, and yeah, I'm not claiming this is particularly efficient, nor does it match the built-in `Array#uniq` (this one requires a block). I was just aiming for a solution that would pass the (rather narrow) Rubeque tests

Comment: Wouldn't `group_by(&block).keys` be more straigtforward?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That wouldn't work, I'm afraid. The  keys produced by `group_by` are the result of the block - not the actual array values. So you wouldn't get the unique values of the original array, but something else. I.e. `[1.1, 2.2].group_by(&:to_i).keys` would give you `[1, 2]` instead of the expected `[1.1, 2.2]`

Comment: Back after almost a month, wondering what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

- Ruby's `Array#uniq` works with and without a block, yours probably should do the same.
- `Array#include?` is O(n), so it's not a good idea to use it within loops. Sets and hashes, on the other hand, do have O(1) inclusion predicates.
- Your solution is very, very imperative (do this, do that), I'd try a more functional approach (based on expressions instead of change of state).

I'd write:

```
class Array
  def my_uniq
    reduce(Hash.new) do |acc, x|
      key = block_given? ? yield(x) : x
      acc.has_key?(key) ? acc : acc.update(key => x)
    end.values
  end
end
```

Note that if we had the abstraction `Hash#reverse_update` in the core (it's in [active_support](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Hash%3areverse_update)) the block could be simplified: `acc.reverse_update((block_given? ? yield(x) : x) => x)`.

Comment: Using Fold without reducing dimensions of a vector looks fun, but is actually bad.

Comment: @Nakilon: why is it bad?

Comment: A slight variant: `each_with_object({}) {|x,acc| acc[block_given? ? yield(x) : x] = x}.values`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Note that you should not override values already present in the accumulator.